# ROracle installation fails on R 2.15.1 using Rtools 2.15

Tags: oracle, r

I'm trying to compile the ROracle package version 1.1-4 under Windows using R 2.15.1 and Rtools 2.15

```
install.packages('ROracle',type='source')
```

but it seems that `ocimingw.c` is missing (see output below). I get the same error message using `R CMD INSTALL --build`.

**edit 2012-09-11**: The problem is apparently specific to 1.1-4, as I managed to build and install 1.1-1 normally.

Any idea what the solution might be?

```
trying URL 'http://stat.ethz.ch/CRAN/src/contrib/ROracle_1.1-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 156924 bytes (153 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 153 Kb

* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
looking for Instant Client c:/instantclient/x64/instantclient_11_2
cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:\instantclient\x64\instantclient_11_2
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/instantclient/x64/instantclient_11_2
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
found Instant Client C:\instantclient\x64\instantclient_11_2
found Instant Client SDK c:/instantclient/x64/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include
generating ocimingw.lib from ocimingw.def
x86_64-w64-mingw32-dlltool: not found
copying from c:/instantclient/x64/instantclient_11_2/sdk/include
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

cygwin warning:
  MS-DOS style path detected: C:/R/R-215~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/R/R-215~1.1/etc/x64/Makeconf
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
    http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
rodbi.c: In function 'rociResExec':
rodbi.c:1169:14: warning: unused variable 'drv' [-Wunused-variable]
rodbi.c: In function 'rociResFetch':
rodbi.c:1187:16: warning: unused variable 'drv' [-Wunused-variable]
rodbi.c: In function 'rociResInfo':
rodbi.c:1256:16: warning: unused variable 'drv' [-Wunused-variable]
rodbi.c: In function 'rociResTerm':
rodbi.c:1323:14: warning: unused variable 'drv' [-Wunused-variable]
rodbi.c: In function 'rodbiCheck':
rodbi.c:2348:25: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'snprintf' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
c:\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/stdio.h:505:15: note: expected 'char * restrict' but argument is of type 'text *'
rodbi.c: In function 'rawToStrhexCall':
rodbi.c:2573:7: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 1 of 'Rf_mkChar' differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
C:/R/R-215~1.1/include/Rinternals.h:628:6: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'unsigned char *'
rodbi.c:2557:26: warning: unused variable 'seglen' [-Wunused-variable]
rodbi.c: In function 'rociResInit':
rodbi.c:1121:3: warning: 'qry_encoding' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
gcc -m64 -I"C:/R/R-215~1.1/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci    -I"d:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
In file included from C:/R/R-215~1.1/include/R.h:44:0,
                 from rodbi.h:37,
                 from rooci.c:47:
C:/R/R-215~1.1/include/R_ext/RS.h:43:0: warning: "ERROR" redefined [enabled by default]
c:\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/wingdi.h:70:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
rooci.c: In function 'roociInitializeRes':
rooci.c:620:32: warning: 'cnvcid' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o ROracle.dll tmp.def rodbi.o rooci.o -L. ocimingw.lib -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib/x64 -Ld:/RCompile/CRANpkg/extralibs64/local/lib -LC:/R/R-215~1.1/bin/x64 -lR
gcc.exe: error: ocimingw.lib: No such file or directory
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'ROracle'
* removing 'C:/R/R-2.15.1/library/ROracle'
```

Comment: Maybe you can ask your question also at the Oracle R discussion forum: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=1397. I had similar issues when installing ROracle 1.1-4 this month.

Comment: @jwijffels could you please give us more details about it? I will post the question to the forum you mentioned, but having more details would certainly help

Answer (score 0):

[ROracle](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/index.html) is quite easy to install from source in Windows, try using Linux if you want to using ROracle from source code, here is [my install log](http://blog.cloud-mes.com/2012/09/16/install-r-and-rstudio-in-ubuntu/).

If still perfer windows, you can get a compiled ROracle package from [Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/r-enterprise/ore-downloads-1502823.html), it's included in the "Client Supporting Packages".

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but apparently it was a version incompatibility issue, as mentioned in my edit - ROracle is indeed supported on windows, but is a bit of a pain to install

Comment: Yes, it is still possible to use ROracle in Windows, I just update my answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is apparently specific to 1.1-4, as I managed to build and install 1.1-1 normally. I will wait for the 1.1-5 version before I give it another try. Thanks to all contributors!